# Check for any timers running in any ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, timer, nstimer

I create and start a self-repeating timer in one of my ViewControllers (let's call it VC1) to have some kind of slideshow of images. When transitioning to any other VC the timer of VC1 appears to keep running as its selector method prints stuff every two seconds. Since this interferes with the timer when returning to VC1 from any other VC I have to remove it at some point.

This is what happens in the console: (runImages() is the timer's selector, the number is the image that should be displayed, as you see its weird...)

[image: console output]

1. I thought the timer would stop once I exit VC1 since I do not save it anywhere. Since this is not the case I thought I might remove the timer when leaving VC1. Is there a method that is being called when VC1 is about to be dismissed?
2. Another approach I had in mind was removing any timers at the beginning of source code of the other VCs. So, when I enter VC2 I want to check for any timers that are running in the project. Is there a way to do that without making the timer a global variable accessible to all VCs?

#### Code Reference

This is how I create the timer: (outside a method)

```
var timer: NSTimer!
```

Then, in a method I set it:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "runImages:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

`runImage()` then increases `i` and calls `changeImage()` which transitions my imageView's image to the image named like `i`.

Thanks in advance :)

### Update

I made the timer a global variable that is accessible to every VC. The app starts up in VC1, then I transitioned to VC2. There, I inserted this code: `if let t = timer {t.invalidate()}` and `if timer.valid {timer.invalidate()}`. Now that made not difference, the timer's selector method keeps printing stuff...

Comment: why dont you invalidate the timer when u exit the VC1 in the viewDidDisappear method ?

Comment: Well that was my question.

Comment: so you are asking how to do it ?

Comment: where did u start the timer and how u moved to VC2 !!!

Comment: Did you actually read what I wrote? Because everything you have asked so far is right in there. I create the timer in VC1 and I do not want it to be available in VC2! I did not move it, that's the case.

Comment: my point is, where did u exactly created the timer and initialised it and how you moved to VC2 ? is it pushed/modally presewnted/ ..... ? how did u came back to VC1 ?......

Comment: where exactly did u put the runImages() ?

Comment: Question updated. `runImages()` is a normal method inside the same class and same VC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95069/discussion-between-mr-t-and-linus-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should keep a reference to the timer in the viewcontroller that is "using" it...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var timer: NSTimer?

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("timerFired"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

  func timerFired() {
    // do whatever you want
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if timer != nil {
      timer?.invalidate()
      timer = nil
    }

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try your code? I'm having issues with `timer = nil`

Comment: we do not know if there will be any other action in his code that invalidated the timer before... so...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let timeInterval: NSTimeInterval = 5 // seconds

    // The run loop maintains a strong reference already.
    weak var timer: NSTimer?

    func startTimer() {
        // 1. invalidate previous timer if necessary
        timer?.invalidate()

        // 2. setup a new timer
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
            timeInterval,
            target: self,
            selector: "timerFired",
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true
        )
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    // Need to include @objc marker here
    // Function must not be private.
    @objc internal func timerFired() {
        /* 
        Perform any UI Updates or whatever... 
        */
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        startTimer()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        stopTimer()
    }
}
```

Comment: my mistake...  Use NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval. I've fixed the example above

Comment: now he is after editing the post ;) @LinusG.: would you like to share your project via dropbox or something?

Comment: It is a company application that I can't share :/

Comment: @AndréSlotta please take back the down vote since the code is valid, just trying to help.  thanks!